# uniqueness of Maximal Independent Set(MIS)

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Is maximal independent set of a graph unique? I think between indepent sets, only one of them is maximal. So does it prove that MIS is unique?

Answer (score 1):

Maximal independent sets are not unique. Consider $Q_{3}$, the hypercube on $8$ vertices. I can select two non-adjacent vertices and up to four non-adjacent vertices depending on my selection. Each such selection is a maximal independent set.

The Wikipedia page has a really nice graphic demonstrating this: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cube-maximal-independence.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCube-maximal-independence.svg)

Note that maximal is not the same as maximum. A maximal independent set is an independent set such that the addition of a vertex will render the set no longer independent. A maximum independent set is a maximal independent $S$ set such that for all other maximal independent sets $X$, $|S| \geq |K|$. So we can have multiple maximum independent sets, but the cardinality is unique.

Comment: Good explanation, but your counterexample is incorrect I think. E.g., If we think about the vertices of $Q_3$ as binary triples, with edges joining triples differing in a single entry, then 000 and 011 are not adjacent, but this is not a maximal independent set since neither are adjacent to 110.

Comment: Thanks for the catch catch! That's what I get for not paying better attention. I'll edit.