# Independent set of edges contained in a maximum independent set of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Every independent set of edges in a graph is contained in a maximum independent set of edges

I know this statement is true but how do I prove it?

Comment: transfinite induction?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what that is. Is it a type of induction?

Comment: My point is that your statement is quite broad.  Did you mean to specify that your graph is finite?

Comment: The statement is not true in fact. E.g., consider a graph consisting of a path on $4$ vertices $v_1-v_2-v_3-v_4$. Then $\{(v_2,v_3)\}$ is an independent set of edges not contained in a *maximum* independent set of edges. Perhaps you meant to say *maximal*?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752330/uniqueness-of-maximal-independent-setmis for the difference between maximum and maximal.